# Registering a file type pattern for a single project in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 10 to work on a craftCMS project, and I'd like to register `*.html` as a pattern for Twig files as [discussed here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10143/6002).

My question: Is there a way to do this in a manner that it will only affect this particular project, allowing my other projects to still use that pattern to identify HTML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...that it will only affect this particular project...

Unfortunately no.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6335 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Right now this ticket is located in "IDEA Backlog" project .. which means that it's quite unlikely that it will be implemented any time soon. Plus, developers clearly stated ([comment 1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6335#comment=27-323128) & [comment 2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6335#comment=27-656948)) that they do not really plan to implement such stuff.

That being said, it is something that could be written into a plugin [(an example)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53520#comment=27-628099).

Answer (score 0):

To use twig in PHPStorm for CraftCMS one can simply rename those .html files to .twig and Craft will load them fine.